# Install gRPC for PHP failed

Tags: php, ubuntu-16.04, grpc

I want to install gRPC to `ubuntu 16.04` for `PHP`. I followed the official [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/php/grpc#build-from-source)

When I run this command:

```
sudo make install
```

I am getting this error:

> Installing via 'make' is no longer supported. Use cmake or bazel
> instead. Please consult BUILDING.md to get more information.

How can I use `cmake` or `bazel` to install? Please, help me

Comment: Why not install that package through PECL?

Comment: PECL website is blocked by my hosting provider. That's why I need manually build

Comment: It wouldn't work anyway, the PECL build takes forever and fails.